# Shipping SSL certificate in Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, ssl, https, dns

I'm writing a utility Mac OS X app that basically acts as a web server accepting incoming HTTP requests (think of it as a mock REST API server).  I want to be able to support HTTPS, but ideally I'd like to remove the requirement for my users to have to purchase their own SSL certificates.

I've been thinking a little on how I might achieve this. Let's say I register a domain called `myapp.com`. I then purchase an SSL cert for `myserver.myapp.com` that is signed by a registered CA.  I ship my app with those SSL cert details embedded within it.  All my users have to do is update their `/etc/hosts` file to point `myserver.myapp.com` to whatever IP address my app is installed and running on.

In fact, by far, the most common scenario would be my app running on the same machine as the client, so I'm considering updating the main DNS entry for `myserver.myapp.com` to point to `127.0.0.1`, and most users wouldn't have to change anything.

So, that's the basic theory. What have I missed that would make this an unworkable plan?  A couple of things that have crossed my mind:

- I could use a self-signed cert. However, many SSL clients barf (or throw up warnings) if the cert doesn't have a valid CA chain. I'm happy to pay the money for a real cert to alleviate this inconvenience for my users.
- I would be embedding the private key for my SSL cert into my app. In theory, someone could extract that and use it to impersonate my app. I guess my reaction is "so what?"  My app is a small productivity app, it isn't an e-commerce site. It doesn't collect sensitive info. It literally just simulates web server responses so devs can test their apps.

Any advice/feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work - but for nontechnical reasons.

Distributing an SSL certificate to your users along with its associated key will violate the issuance terms of your SSL certificate provider, and they will revoke the certificate when they discover what you have done. (This happened, for example, [when Pivotal tried to offer SSL service for developers through sslip.io](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/sslip-io-a-valid-ssl-certificate-for-every-ip-address).) This will, of course, cause your application to stop working.

If your users have administrative access to their machines, they can [create and trust their own self-signed CA using Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20132?locale=en_US). Once they have done so, they could create a certificate (again, using Keychain Access) and insert that into your application to enable SSL.

Comment: Hmm... that is very interesting - I didn't know that. I wonder if there is (at least) one SSL provider that has a slightly looser interpretation as to what "compromised" means.

Certainly producing self-signed certs is an option. I can hide a lot of the self-signed cert nonsense within the app, but my users will still have to import the signing cert as a trusted cert into their clients (consider the case where an iPhone/Android mobile app is pointing at my Mac app). I was hoping I could avoid that whole dance and the support nightmare that will come with it.

Thanks for your insight though.

Comment: @CraigEdwards re. providers: if there is, their certificates aren't trusted by your OS (or won't be for much longer). The [CA/Browser Forum](https://cabforum.org/) sets a number of requirements regarding CA's handling of key compromises; revoking certificates that the owner has lost control of is one of those requirements.

Comment: In any case, the `/etc/hosts` hack wouldn't work for mobile devices, because they don't have that file accessible. But you can insert trusted certificates into those devices, e.g. by creating a configuration profile for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the link to CAB forum... according to https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.3.3.pdf, a Key Compromise is defined as "A Private Key is said to be compromised if its value has been disclosed to an unauthorized person, an unauthorized person has had access to it, or there exists a practical technique by which an unauthorized person may discover its value." Academically speaking, I guess I'm saying that everybody is "authorised" to my key :-) Practically speaking, though, I am certain you are correct and I need to find another solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer you can't ship the same certificate for everybody. What you could do is generate different for everybody:

1. The application ask them the domain name they want to use (a domain they must own, like myapp.example.com)
2. The application use the ACME protocol to get automatically a trusted certificate from let's encrypt

Note: you can provide them subdomains of a domain you control (like [clientid].yourappname.yourdomain.com) ONLY of you can register yourappname.yourdomain.com in the public suffix list (because let's encrypt have rate limits)

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely one option. It is just more moving parts that I'd need to support. But definitely appreciate the option..